# Issues Building Apex Theme in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a php programmer looking to get into android development, as well as a graphic designer so I figured I'd start by making an Apex launcher theme. I've been following this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1649891 guide as a starting point, and am mostly certain I've followed every step to the letter. But when I go to build the sample icon theme dennisxl (the author) recommends using as a base, everything goes to hell. I hope I'll get to the point where I can decipher these error messages soon, but for now I'm a noobie and that amount of errors that I'm having trouble fixing one at a time even with Google's help is the kind of nightmare that deters people before they even get started.

Any clues? Help appreciated!

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nb6pcKwZ

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. It seems like a good clean was all it needed and it builds fine with only a few warnings.